# Storing array or std object in database of Laravel app

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

What is the schema for the database table to store Array or stdObject in a column ?

When I use ->string and insert an array variable, it only stores the word "Array" in the db column.

does Laravel has support for array?

If no, What methodology should I implement?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can save/insert serialized data in to a `TEXT` type field but for this you have to something using `php`, for example:

```
$arr = array('x', 'y', 'z');
```

To insert this into a database field you can use [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function like this

```
$serializedArr = serialize($arr);
```

Now, you can insert the `$serializedArr` array in to databse and when you retrieve the data to use, just [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it using somethig like:

```
$record = SomeModel::find(1);
unserialize($record->field_name);
```

Also, you can use, Laravel's [accessors-and-mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent?/docs/eloquent/#accessors-and-mutators) to make the whole thing automated, check the manual, it's dead simple. If you need more help on this `accessors-and mutators` then leave a message with your `table` details.

**Update:**

Since `Laravel 5.x` allows [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#attribute-casting) so it's possible to cast attributes to another data type for converting on runtime. In this case, just declare a `protected $casts` property for example:

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_admin' => 'boolean', // Will convarted to (Bool)
    'options' => 'array', // Will convarted to (Array)
];
```

The `array` cast is particularly useful for working with columns that are stored as serialized `JSON`. For example, if your database has a `TEXT` type field that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a `PHP` array when you access it on your `Eloquent` model and also it'll be automatically serialized back to `JSON` when you set value to this property, for example:

```
$user = User::find(1);

// $options is an array...
$options = $user->options;

// options is automatically serialized back to JSON...
$user->options = ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

Comment: thx, indeed dead simple using accessors and mutators and in my case very applicable

Comment: why don't you use CASTing? Please read my answer for details.

Comment: What did you do when you want to edit that stored  data?

Comment: `unserialize($record->field_name);` returns an array so change it and then save it in the database again.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, The answer was given when the `casting` was not available but now, yes, `cast` it simply.

Comment: @TheAlpha, Thank you, I did not know that casting was not available. It feels so organic to me. I do it even then using raw php.

Comment: @TheAlpha, I use `unserialize($record->field_name);` . but i have error on server (local is OK) . `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @MN, Check the return value of `unserialize($record->field_name)`, or do it like `$data = (array) unserialize($record->field_name)`, if you are expecting an array.

Comment: @The Alpha, Verrrrrrrrry Thanks. `(array)` solved my problem.

Answer (score 16):

The best way since Laravel 5.1 is to CAST your table field like this:

```
class Mytable extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'my_field' => 'array',
    ];
```

Read more about attribute casting on [official documents page](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) of Laravel.
The quote:

> The $casts property on your model provides a convenient method of
>   converting attributes to common data types. The $casts property should
>   be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast,
>   while the value is the type you wish to cast to the column to. The
>   supported cast types are: *integer, real, float, double, string,
>   boolean, object, **array**, collection, date and datetime*.

The only **limitation** that docs does not say is that you **cannot** work with this array directly, like this

```
$myTable.my_field[]='new array element';
```

instead, you have to prepare array separately and then assign it to the field,  like this:

```
$temp=[];
$temp[]='new array element';
$myTable.my_field[]=$temp;
```

If you use older version of Laravel, please use an answer providerd by **The Alpha**, or even better, quit your job :).