# Advanced search query using multiple, and varied queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Currently, a user can add a criteria which is searched amongst our database to find any matching results. This is working perfectly, however, there is now a need to 'enhance' the search. To help make things clearer, there is a working example below:

**Scenario**

A user wants to `buy` a property:

1. Within a certain `location`
2. Which has `4` bedrooms
3. Is `detached`
4. Within the price range of $300k - $500k.

This is added to the database, and then the function below finds any matching properties (shortened):

```
$locations = Location::whereHas('coordinate', function ($q) use 
                               ($bedrooms, $property_type)
            {
                $q->where('bedrooms', '=', $bedrooms)
                ->where('type', '=', $property_type);

            })->lists('id');
```

So as you can see, the query is pretty 'set' on just querying `one` number of bedrooms and `one` property type' - it's just one variable on the same row!

**Now, the problem.**

Currently, a user can add one preference of bedrooms, `type of house` etc... The change is to add `multiple choice` for bedrooms, `type of house` etc... So the new `query` would be for a user:

**Proposed scenario**

1. Within a certain `location` (this is always one location)
2. Which has `3,4,5,6` bedrooms
3. Is `detached, studio, semi-detached, bungalow`
4. Within the price range of $300k - $500k. (always a range).

My question is mainly advice, how can I store such a query, and then query it back to return any properties that match their criteria. Each criteria currently exists on one row, but I imagine I'll have to have a separate table to store the number of bedrooms etc...?

Also, for example, if one user only wants `1` bedrooms and `detached, studio, semi-detached, bungalow`, as opposed to another user whose criteria may be far more in depth, how can a query accommodate this?

> Instead of completely redesigning my tables, could I not serialize the
>   number of bedrooms etc.. and then store them in VARCHAR, and
>   un-serialize them on request?

I hope I've explained things clearly, including providing my current code. If you require further information please just let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it a stored procedure with input parameters.

Comment: Could you explain further please @DanBracuk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use logic to control the where clauses depending on what values are set and/or if they are an array. Instead of chaining the where statements you could write:

```
//bedrooms (required, mixed)
if(is_array($bedrooms)){
    $q->whereIn('bedrooms', $bedrooms)
}else{
    $q->where('bedrooms', '=', $bedrooms)
}
//type (required, mixed)
if(is_array($property_type)){
    $q->whereIn('type', $property_type)
}else{
    $q->where('type', '=', $property_type)
}
//minimum price (optional, int)
if(isset($min_price)){
    $q->where('price', '>=' , $min_price)
}
//maximum price (optional, int)
if(isset($max_price)){
    $q->where('price', '<=' , $max_price)
}
```

This is just a fast example based on what you provided but I would probably see how you could refactor the call or the values you are passing to the query to try and increase the code readability.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this makes sense. The second part to this would be the most effective way of storing such information within my database. Currently, each `criteria` only has one row, but what would you recommend to store multiple values of bedrooms, property types etc...

Comment: You mean it is currently like a meta table? As in criteria is a table like `property_id, criteria, value`? Short answer is there is no right way. Meta is great for dynamic search criteria and flexibility but poor for performance and integrity. My answer would be subjective rather than objective and I do not feel I could properly answer this question with the information provided. I will say I would not refactor any current db design unless there is good reason or you are piling "technical debt" because of the current design.

Comment: Right ok. Instead of completely redesigning my tables, could I not `serialize` the number of bedrooms etc.. and then store them in `VARCHAR`, and un-serialize them on request? [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658926/storing-array-or-std-object-in-database-of-laravel-app).

Comment: Oh! All the values are serialized in one field in one row. Not one row per value in a table. That I would probably change... a quick way would be a table like `id, property_id, key, value`. Many sites/CMS do this when there is high potential for lots of nulls or variance in the data. But for sure things like all properties will have rooms, price, square footage then this could belong in the main property table. Sadly I have a meeting to attend to so I will have to leave you hanging.

Comment: So that best way to do it would be to have another table, related to the `criteria` table, with all the variances of bedrooms, property types etc..?