# eloquent orm - putting an array

Tags: laravel

How can I make a column for putting arrays in a database migration in Laravel for use of eloquent ORM? i.e. I want to make the following possible:

```
class Foo extends Model {
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$foo->save;
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658926/storing-array-or-std-object-in-database-of-laravel-app

Answer (score 0):

Using `serialize()` function:

```
  $foo=new foo();
  $scores=array(1,2,3);
  $foo->scores=serialize($scores);
  $foo->save();
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. You are putting a string rather than an array into the model. What I want is that I can assign and retrieve an array directly.

Comment: @Michael  And i guess rdbms doesnot support array data types.

Comment: sorry, Propel allowed me to put in arrays and objects in the ORM