# How to insert an array to database in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How to  insert an array to database in Laravel 5.6
Array in controller

```
public function insert(Request $request )
{
    $idsArry = $request->input('id'); 

    DB::table('work_user')->insert(array(['WorkID' => $idsArry]));

    return redirect ("/works_assign")->with("Success", "Deleted Successfully") ;
}
```

Comment: `json_encode(['WorkID'=>$idsArry])` your array and save it in a varchar or text

Comment: you would like to insert multiple row for each id in $idsArry there; or you can just json_encode() the array and json_decode() to get data back.

Comment: plz post your `work_user` structure.

Comment: And plz post `$idsArry` too?

Comment: Id       int(11) 
WorkID  int(11) 
CusName  varchar(100)       $idsArry=[1,2,3];  @TsaiKoga

Comment: @TestCheck So I think you want to insert the work_user with `cusName` and `workID`, however, you are inserting array only including `workID`, and another question: is $request->input('id') is a number ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing array or std object in database of Laravel app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658926/storing-array-or-std-object-in-database-of-laravel-app)

Comment: yes its a number @TsaiKoga

Comment: So you need to get the column value from the `$request` and insert it, like `DB::table('work_user')->insert(['WorkID' => $request->id, 'cusName' => $request->cusName])`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $array = [
    'one' => $one,
    'two' => $two,
    'nine' => $nine,
    'ten' => $ten,
   ];

  YourModel::create($array)
```

Comment: @ArunVinoth this is easy, just put array in create() and it will work